# A basic question about Scatter Graph

Tags: statistics

The question is asking to plot a scatter graph of the maths scores against the science scores for each pupil. (Data is given).

My doubt is what to take on $x$-axis and what on $y$-axis?

Comment: Take one of the scores on X-axis and the other on Y-axis and plot for each pupil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would interpret "plot A against B" to mean A goes on the $y$-axis and B on the $x$-axis. However, I don't think it's important which is which; you get the same information either way.

Comment: Thanks, Especially Lime.